# Encountering Errors Running GitHub Project: Adaptive learning attention network for underwater image enhancement - Seeking Assistance

Tags: python

I was running  a github code and i encounterd this error

```
PS C:\Users\91789\Desktop\Underwater-Image-Enhancement\LANet> Python train.py --input_images-path C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish.jpeg ./data/trainA/ --label_images_path C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish2.jpg ./data/trainB/ 
logs/
usage: train.py [-h] [--input_images_path INPUT_IMAGES_PATH] [--label_images_path LABEL_IMAGES_PATH] [--lr LR] [--cuda_id CUDA_ID] [--decay_rate DECAY_RATE]
                [--num_epochs NUM_EPOCHS] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--resize RESIZE] [--snapshots_folder SNAPSHOTS_FOLDER] [--loss_folder LOSS_FOLDER]
                [--data_folder DATA_FOLDER] [--resume RESUME]
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --input_images-path
```

```
C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish.jpeg ./data/trainA/ ./data/trainB/
PS C:\Users\91789\Desktop\Underwater-Image-Enhancement\LANet> Python train.py C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish.jpeg ./data/trainA/ C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish2.jpg ./data/trainB/                                        
logs/
usage: train.py [-h] [--input_images_path INPUT_IMAGES_PATH] [--label_images_path LABEL_IMAGES_PATH] [--lr LR] [--cuda_id CUDA_ID] [--decay_rate DECAY_RATE]
                [--num_epochs NUM_EPOCHS] [--batch_size BATCH_SIZE] [--resize RESIZE] [--snapshots_folder SNAPSHOTS_FOLDER] [--loss_folder LOSS_FOLDER]
                [--data_folder DATA_FOLDER] [--resume RESUME]
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish.jpeg ./data/trainA/ C:\Users\91789\Desktop\fish2.jpg ./data/trainB/
```

This is github link: https://github.com/LiuShiBen/LANet

Please let me know how to run this code and what is the error in this...

Comment: Typo? --input_images_path has an underscore. Your errors say you gave a dash, or no flag at all

Comment: can u pls let me know how to run this code from the start

Comment: The README.md file says: *"If you have any questions, please contact Shiben Liu at liushiben310@163.com."*   Have you done that?

Comment: The readme has a typo. `--input_images_path` with underscore needs to be given, and needs to point to a folder, not one jpg file... data/trainA or data/trainB are example paths that do not exist in that repository, so aren't valid examples for you to run. You're also missing `--label_images_path` in the second execution

Comment: I under stood what is error in one folder i will keep a input image and in another folder what should i keep

Comment: You'll need to ask the person that wrote the code, but there's comments that say "clear images", so I'd guess it's pictures of the same things, just not underwater

Comment: raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled") AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled now i got this as  an error

Comment: Why are you still posting comments instead of contacting the author of the code?